# Redux state is nested after call an action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I habe a small problem:

my reducer

```
const initialObject = {
    counter: 0,
    messages: []
};

function message(state = initialObject, action) {
    switch(action.type) {

        case actions.ADD_MESSAGE:
            return state; // do nothing just return the same state, expect to equal initialObject
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const testApp = combineReducers({
   message
});
```

in my main file I have a call on action

```
let store = createStore(reducers);

let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
    console.log(store.getState())
);

store.dispatch(actions.addMessage("sine text"));
```

And the problem is, the object I see in the console after "subscribe"

[image]

it is nested... any idea why? This happens only after an action call.

Comment: this is not all the code... I guess.. there must be something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is because of this line

```
const testApp = combineReducers({
   message
});
```

In ES6, this

```
{ message }
```

is the same as this:

```
{ message: message }
```

So your state is an object, with keys. In this example it has only one key: `message`

From the Readme:  https://www.github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/Reducers.md

> All combineReducers() does is generate a function that calls your reducers with the slices of state selected according to their keys, and combining their results into a single object again. It’s not magic.

Comment: according the documenation https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/Reducers.md combineReducers just combines multiple reducers... it has nothing to do with state.

Comment: Sure it has.. it combines the reducers, and the object defines the structure.. like the state object in the reducers itself